# If statement in Django JSON method

Tags: django, json, django-models

If I have a Building object with a ForeignKey Campus object, how would I modify the Building's JSON method so it doesn't look as ugly as this:

```
def json(self):
    if self.campus:
        return {
        'id_number': self.id,
        'campus': self.campus.json(),
        'common_name': self.common_name,
        #....all the other fields
        }

    else:
        return {
        'id_number': self.id,
        'common_name': self.common_name,
        #....all the other fields
        }
```

The code above works.  I was wondering if there was a way to format the if statement such that I could relocate it and not have to list out all the other fields for both if-branches.  Mainly because this would get even messier if I had another relational object that was null, blank=True.

Comment: How does it "yell at you"? What is the error?

Comment: See my edit (sorry for the confusion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid defining the other fields twice.

```
def json(self):
    out = {
    'id_number': self.id,
    'common_name': self.common_name,
    #....all the other fields
    }
    if self.campus:
        out['campus'] = self.campus.json()
    return out
```

Note that this method and your original method return a python dict, not a JSON encoded string.

Comment: That was what I was trying to work-around -- thanks!  And yes, sorry for the improper terminology.